# Yet Another "The input is not a valid Base-64 string..."

Tags: c#, multithreading, encryption, aes

So I've used some AES encrypt/decrypt methods that I've seen over the net that I modified a little. The methods are written below.

```
public void EncryptStringAES(Object threadContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputData))
            {
                outputData = string.Empty;
                doneEventProperty.Set();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecretData))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            string outStr = null;
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecretData, saltData);

                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                    msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(inputData);
                        }
                    }
                    outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            outputData = outStr;
            doneEventProperty.Set();
        }

        public void DecryptStringAES(Object threadContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputData))
            {
                outputData = string.Empty;
                doneEventProperty.Set();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecretData))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            string plaintext = null;

            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecretData, saltData);

                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputData.ToString());
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                    aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);

                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            outputData = plaintext;
            doneEventProperty.Set();
        }
```

I modified it so that the object where these codes were used could be queued on the thread pool and hopefully make the whole encryption/decryption process quicker. Before I modified the code for threading, it works. But after I added the threading capabilities, I always encounter this error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

This always happens when I decrypt the string that I encrypted. Below are examples of the data that I encrypted.

```
EAAAALlZu0F1HmtQ0pNO/xPoOBgr4zRJvhIyr43van78dDED
EAAAAIvlxL+vtqhAf3HCFpRc6xeb76KFqhfe6Tbu1SN7LZH1
```

I've checked the requirements of Base64 strings and these pretty much comply with the requirements. I also tried all possible answers that I saw here in stackoverflow but to no avail still. What's even worse, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm running out of options here so can anybody help me?

UPDATE:

Below are some code where the said methods were used.

```
class AESHandler
    {
        private string outputDataProperty;
        private string inputDataProperty;
        private byte[] saltDataProperty;
        private string sharedSecretDataProperty;
        private ManualResetEvent doneEventProperty;
        private Guid signatureDataProperty;

        public string outputData
        {
            get
            {
                return outputDataProperty;
            }
            private set
            {
                outputDataProperty = value;
            }
        }

        private string inputData
        {
            get
            {
                return inputDataProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                inputDataProperty = value;
            }
        }

        private byte[] saltData
        {
            get
            {
                return saltDataProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                saltDataProperty = value;
            }
        }

        private string sharedSecretData
        {
            get
            {
                return sharedSecretDataProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                sharedSecretDataProperty = value;
            }
        }

        public ManualResetEvent doneEvent
        {
            get
            {
                return doneEventProperty;
            }
        }

        public Guid signatureData
        {
            get
            {
                return signatureDataProperty;
            }
            private set
            {
                signatureDataProperty = value;
            }
        }


        private byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
        {
            byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
            if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
            }

            return buffer;
        }


        public void EncryptStringAES(Object threadContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputData))
            {
                outputData = string.Empty;
                doneEventProperty.Set();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecretData))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            string outStr = null;
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecretData, saltData);

                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                    msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(inputData);
                        }
                    }
                    outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            outputData = outStr;
            doneEventProperty.Set();
        }

        public void DecryptStringAES(Object threadContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputData))
            {
                outputData = string.Empty;
                doneEventProperty.Set();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecretData))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            string plaintext = null;

            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecretData, saltData);

                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputData.ToString());
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                    aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);

                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            outputData = plaintext;
            doneEventProperty.Set();
        }


        public AESHandler(string input, string sharedSecret, Guid signature, byte[] salt)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                inputData = input;
            }
            else
            {
                inputData = string.Empty;
            }

            sharedSecretData = sharedSecret;
            signatureData = signature;
            saltData = salt;
            doneEventProperty = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }
    }
```

That's the actual code that handles the encryption/decryption process. The code below creates an instance of the class above and queue it in the thread pool.

```
public sealed partial class AESCore
    {
        private static List<AESHandler> encryptThreadList = new List<AESHandler>();

        public static Guid AESQueueEncrypt(string input, string sharedSecret)
        {
            return AESQueueEncrypt(input, sharedSecret, EncryptionCore._salt);
        }

        public static Guid AESQueueEncrypt(string input, string sharedSecret, byte[] salt)
        {
            Guid queueID = Guid.NewGuid();

            AESHandler handle = new AESHandler(input, sharedSecret, queueID, EncryptionCore._salt);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(handle.EncryptStringAES);

            encryptThreadList.Add(handle);

            return queueID;
        }

        public static Guid AESQueueDecrypt(string input, string sharedSecret)
        {
            return AESQueueDecrypt(input, sharedSecret, EncryptionCore._salt);
        }

        public static Guid AESQueueDecrypt(string input, string sharedSecret, byte[] salt)
        {
            Guid queueID = Guid.NewGuid();

            AESHandler handle = new AESHandler(input, sharedSecret, queueID, EncryptionCore._salt);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(handle.DecryptStringAES);

            encryptThreadList.Add(handle);

            return queueID;
        }

        public static string AESFetchData(Guid signature)
        {
            var data = encryptThreadList.Where(s => s.signatureData == signature).FirstOrDefault();
            string output = data.outputData;
            encryptThreadList.Remove(data);

            return output;
        }

        public static void AESProcessWait()
        {
            foreach (var d in encryptThreadList)
            {
                d.doneEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage is like this:

Encryption

```
Guid strnNameLast = Encryption.AESCore.AESQueueEncrypt(user.strnNameLast, publicKeyToken);
Guid strnNameFirst = Encryption.AESCore.AESQueueEncrypt(user.strnNameFirst, publicKeyToken);

Encryption.AESCore.AESProcessWait();

string strnNameLastEncrypted = Encryption.AESCore.AESFetchData(strnNameLast);
string strnNameFirstEncrypted = Encryption.AESCore.AESFetchData(strnNameFirst);
```

Decryption:

```
Guid strnNameLast = Encryption.AESCore.AESQueueDecrypt(user.strnNameLast, publicKeyToken);
Guid strnNameFirst = Encryption.AESCore.AESQueueDecrypt(user.strnNameFirst, publicKeyToken);

Encryption.AESCore.AESProcessWait();

string strnNameLastDecrypted = Convert.ToString(Encryption.AESCore.AESFetchData(strnNameLast));
string strnNameFirstDecrypted = Convert.ToString(Encryption.AESCore.AESFetchData(strnNameFirst));
```

Comment: Depending on how you're using the methods in multithreading, the `inputData` might still be set to the value it had in encryptStringAES, and therefore might not be a valid Base64 string yet: you must synchronize access to inputData and other shared values in multithreaded situations.

Comment: Both methods belong to the same class. But the instance of that class would only do one: if the instance is meant to encrypt, it'll encrypt and nothing else. Same goes for decrypt. I also checked the inputData's value when the error occurred and counter-checked it against the result of encryption. The output of encryption and the input of decryption are the same string, at least as how I see it.

Comment: `The output of encryption and the input of decryption are the same string, at least as how I see it` Probably not, since the base64 strings you posted above are valid.

Comment: Make inputData, outputData and the rest (sharedSecret) parameters.

Comment: this line here: byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputData.ToString()); inputData is a string. I just placed the string.ToString() there with the hopes of making it work. But unfortunately it didn't. As for the value of inputData in Decrypt, I'm sure that its value is one of those mentioned above. When the error occurred, I even checked its value and as a matter of fact, that's where I got those.

Comment: I must agree with @PeterO. You seem to be running into thread synchronisation problems. It is however very difficult to say exactly what you're doing wrong if we do not have the full picture/code of what you are doing (especially the parts that set the input strings and running the threaded methods). Also, the very fact that EncryptStringAES(Object threadContext) is a public method is also a sign of code smell. Post more code if you need constructive help.

Comment: Ok, but look at your code that calls the decryption methods. The input is the unencrypted strings (user.strnNameLast), not the encrypted strings that you returned from the encryption methods. Also, as a hint, you could simplify your async code 10-fold by using the TPL in .NET

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't clear that out. user, the one you see there having a property named strnNameLast and strnNameFirst, was actually output from a query, which contains encrypted strings generated by EncryptStringAES method. They're exactly the examples that I provided above. As for TPL, that was actually my first option. However I'm not sure how to make multiple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem at last. Actually I devised a simple Blowfish implementation on each string properties. Apparently there were some problems in decryption that I can't explain as of now (although the output according to the debugger is a valid base-64 string). I removed the encryption and it worked.

Comment: Good. But you'll make your life easier if you learn the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Comment: I actually found the TPL very useful. In fact I'm using it on other parts of my program. However I'm not really sure how to use it when I need it to work like a thread pool. Pardon me if in fact they do the same thing. This is the first time I tried using threads on my applications.